# Yahoo query does not work

Tags: vb.net, web

I have created an excel that using a vba code access yahoo web site to fetch stocks data.

The excel works fine most of the time but sometimes (and I can't find a rule/ motivation) it does not get the data from yahoo.

The strange thing is that if I do it step by step using the debugger it works but if I start the macro it does not work and  am not able to fetch the data.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks,

Giancarlo

Below the subs I use t retrieve the data ...

```
Sub StrongestSmallCaps()
Dim frequency As String
Dim numRows As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim stockTicker As String
Dim IndR As Integer
Dim Simbolo As String
Dim rsi As String
Dim ShortInter As Boolean
Dim NonIncr As Boolean
Worksheets("GreenLine").Select
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp).Row
frequency = "d"



'Cancella contenuti celle stocastici
Range("j2:k70").Clear
Range("j2:k70").Select
Selection.Style = "Stocastic"

Range("i2:i70").Clear
Range("i2:i70").Select
Selection.Style = "Tick"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
IndR = 2
'Loop through all tickers
For Ticker = 2 To LastRow

    'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    stockTicker = Worksheets("GreenLine").Range("$h$" & Ticker)

    If stockTicker = "" Then
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = stockTicker

    Cells(1, 1) = "Stock Quotes for " & stockTicker
    Call DownloadStockQuotes(stockTicker, Worksheets("GreenLine").Range("$b$500"), Worksheets("GreenLine").Range("$b$600"), "$a$2", frequency)

    'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Columns("a:a").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                 TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                                 Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1))
    Sheets(stockTicker).Columns("A:G").ColumnWidth = 10


    LastRow = Sheets(stockTicker).UsedRange.Row - 2 + Sheets(stockTicker).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If LastRow < 3 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(stockTicker).delete
        GoTo NextIteration
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.INSERT Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    'CALCOLA STOCHASTIC
    Worksheets("GreenLine").Select
    Range("Cb100:Cm122").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("GreenLine").Select
    Sheets(stockTicker).Select
    Range("e1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    If Cells(3, 8) < 20 Then
        Worksheets("GreenLine").Select

        Cells(IndR, 9) = stockTicker
        Cells(IndR, 10) = "BUY"
        Cells(IndR, 10).Select
        Selection.Style = "Oversold"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(stockTicker).delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'CALCOLA RSI
        'Sheets(stockTicker).Select

        'If Cells(3, 16) < 20 Then
        '     rsi = Cells(3, 16)
        '     Worksheets("GreenLine").Select
        '
        '     Cells(IndR, 9) = stockTicker
        '     Cells(IndR, 11) = "OVS"
        '     Cells(IndR, 11).Select
        '     Selection.Style = "Oversold"
        '     Selection.Style = "Comma"
        '     IndR = IndR + 1

        '     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        '     Sheets(stockTicker).delete
        '     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Else
        '     IndR = IndR + 1
        '     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        '     Sheets(stockTicker).delete
        '     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'End If
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(stockTicker).delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Sheets(stockTicker).Select
        'If Cells(3, 16) < 20 Then
        '     rsi = Cells(3, 16)
        '     Worksheets("GreenLine").Select
        '
        '     Cells(IndR, 9) = stockTicker
        '     Cells(IndR, 11) = "OVS"
        '     Cells(IndR, 11).Select
        '     Selection.Style = "Oversold"
        '     Selection.Style = "Comma"
        '
        '     IndR = IndR + 1
        '     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        '     Sheets(stockTicker).delete
         '    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Else
        '     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        '     Sheets(stockTicker).delete
        '     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'End If
    End If

NextIteration:
Next Ticker

ErrorHandler:

Worksheets("GreenLine").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Range("h2:h70").Clear
Range("h2:h70").Select
Selection.Style = "Normal"

E
```

nd Sub

```
Sub DownloadStockQuotes(ByVal stockTicker As String, ByVal startDate As Date, ByVal endDate As Date, ByVal DestinationCell As String, ByVal freq As String)

Dim qurl As String
Dim StartMonth, StartDay, StartYear, EndMonth, EndDay, EndYear As String
StartMonth = Format(Month(Date) - 8, "00")
StartDay = Format(Day(Date), "00")
StartYear = Format(Year(Date), "00")

EndMonth = Format(Month(Date) - 1, "00")
EndDay = Format(Day(Date), "00")
EndYear = Format(Year(Date), "00")
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
qurl = "URL;http://table.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + stockTicker + "&a=" + StartMonth + "&b=" + StartDay + "&c=" + StartYear + "&d=" + EndMonth + "&e=" + EndDay + "&f=" + EndYear + "&g=" + freq + "&ignore=.csv"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=qurl, Destination:=Range(DestinationCell))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "20"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
ErrorHandler:

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it really "works in debugger" and "doesn't work running on its own"? If so, could it be a security issue?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I issue this command first
On Error Resume Next ' this should get past 1004 errors but No Data will show in my error column

Then after I fetch the data, I check to see if there is really any data there and if not, I run the query again.
For some unknown reason it randomly fails and almost always works the second time.

But I hope you already solved your problem since it was posted so long ago.